# Bootstrap Well Aligning Text and Dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to align the a string and dropdown menu within a well using bootstrap. I would like the string ("1.0 HEADER) to be on the far left then the dropdown menu to be on the far left. However at the moment the dropbox is under the header. I've tried using CSS float without any success.

```
  <div class="well well-sm well-gapHeader" >
    <span style:"float:left" >1.0 HEADER</span>

    <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
      <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="float:right" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
          DROPBOX<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li ng-click="gapHeader.isApplicable=true"><a href="#">Applicable</a></li>
          <li ng-click="gapHeader.isApplicable=false"><a href="#">Not-Applicable</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

I'm using Angular with Bootsrap and UI Bootstrap

Comment: Your question is clearly about styling. Why did you tag it with Angular?

Comment: Noted I have changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pull-left` and `pull-right` helper classes to float the elements to the left and right. You'll need a `clearfix` class on the `well` to make it contain the floated elements.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="well well-sm well-gapHeader clearfix">
  <span class="pull-left">1.0 HEADER</span>

  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl" class="pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        DROPBOX<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-click="gapHeader.isApplicable=true"><a href="#">Applicable</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-click="gapHeader.isApplicable=false"><a href="#">Not-Applicable</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to add a `row` containing two columns inside the well, and to put each element in its respective column.

**P.S.** The floating doesn't work in your example as you have a typo. The `:` in `style:"float:left"` should be a `=` like `style="float:left"`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! Sorry the style was a typo, I actually used a cSS style sheet but it was easier to explain everything through the an in-line style. One thing with the text what would be the best CSS property so it centers vertically within the Well? Thanks again.

Comment: I already thought it was a typo added when creating this question, just wanted to be sure. Bootstrap has some [Type Alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) classes you can use. To center text for example use `.text-center`.

Comment: Sorry for misreading your comment, you meant center vertically instead of horizontally. Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for all different centering options. You'll have to create your own classes for vertical centering, it doesn't exist in Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks that is a great link, I have bookmarked it for future reference!